# In Firebase Realtime Database, how can an unauthenticated third-party server (using the Admin SDK) read unprotected data from my database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Regarding the Firebase Realtime Database Admin SDK, in JAVA:

I have some info, in the database, which is not secret, and I allow its reading by unauthenticated devices. But I also need to let any third-party SERVERS read this info.

However, how can a server, using the Admin SDK, connect to my database without credentials:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()                  
          .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/")                  
          .build();
```

The above code doesn't work:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: FirebaseOptions must be initialized with setCredentials().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you need admin credentials to initialize the SDK.  That's because the implication with using the Admin SDK is that you want admin access to the resources in a Firebase projects.  If you don't want admin access, don't use the Admin SDK.  Instead you can use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/).

Comment: Doug, I hope you are not getting tired of me asking Firebase authorization questions.

Comment: I thought the client SDK was only for Android, iOS and web. Is there a client SDK for Java, that a third-party server can use?

Comment: Well, I thought you were asking about JavaScript, in which case, the client SDK works on node.js.  But the Android SDK doesn't work in a non-Android environment, so my answer doesn't make sense.  I'll edit it.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the Firestore Admin SDK lets you connect to any database to read and even write unprotected data, without asking for authentication. I'm surprised that the Realtime database doesn't allow for that. The REST API is more complicated and won't allow listening to changes, right?

Comment: Please read the REST docs I linked.  It allows for streaming for changes at a location.  If you have equivalent Firestore code to mimic, please post that. (I suspect you would not be using the Admin SDK's wrapper around the Firestore SDK in that case.)

Comment: The equivalent Firestore code to mimic is this: `FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build(); Firestore db = firestoreOptions.getService();`

Comment: And you're saying you don't need a service account credential to make that happen?

Comment: Exactly. But I can read/write only unprotected documents, since there is no auth. For example: `allow read, write: if true;`. That seems the right behavior. If I'm not authenticated, why should I need a service account?

Comment: To be more versatile, both Firestore and RT should let us contact any database without a service account (unauthenticated). And both should let us call `.setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(auth)`. This would allow for a microservice architecture where many servers from different companies alter a single database, with different permissions. I have some very interesting use cases that are not possible because Firebase authorization for servers is not flexible.

Comment: If the Admin SDK doesn't do what you want, please file a feature request to make that statement.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/